# How to loop over [object Object] using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I am trying to loop through this array using *ngFor like this.

```
  let geographicalArea  = [{
    "_id": "5e77f43e48348935b4571fa7",
    "name": "Latin America",
    "employee": {
      "_id": "5e77c50c4476e734d8b30dc6",
      "name": "Thomas",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "_v": 0
    },
    "_v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e77ff92165aa2060c54a5aa",
    "name": "Oceania",
    "employee": {
      "_id": "5e76c50c4476e734d8b30dc6",
      "name": "Joe",
      "lastName": "Duff",
      "_v": 0
    },
    "_v": 0
  }]
```

Html, but when i try to get the employee name it returns me `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

```
<tr *ngFor="let geo of geographicalArea | keyvalue">
                        <td>{{geo.value.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{geo.value.employee.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

i try to show only the employee but it return`[object Object]`

```
<tr *ngFor="let geo of geographicalArea | keyvalue">
                        <td>{{geo.value.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{geo.value.employee}}</td>
</tr>
```

I looked for the way to go through an object inside an object and I found the pipe keyvalue but it does not return the information of the employee, which would be the most appropriate way to obtain this information using this pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `keyvalue` pipe to loop through `geographicalArea` because it is an array. However if you want to loop through each `employee` inside `geographicalArea` then you need `keyvalue` pipe because it is an object.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let geo of geographicalArea">
  <td>{{geo.name}}</td>
  <td>{{geo.employee.name}}</td>
  <div *ngFor="let employee of geo.employee | keyvalue">
    {{ employee.key }} : {{ employee.value }}
  </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks.I thought that with the pipe I could iterate the object without creating another * ngFor, that works for me

Answer (score 0):

**You can loop over array and directly access inner object property, using `dot` operator.**

```
<tr *ngFor="let geo of geographicalArea">
  <td>{{geo.name}}</td>
  <td>{{geo.employee.name}}</td>
</tr>
```